# VS 2008 Debugging: System.ArgumentException?

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, argumentexception

**The Problem:** 
I have a forms project which instantiates a class that is defined in a separate dll project.  When running the forms application which uses this dll everything runs perfectly fine, *however*, when I set a breakpoint to inspect objects of types that are defined in the dll project I get errors in my watch window.

Some things that may be important to know:

1. The dll project uses unsafe and unmanaged code.
2. This problem occurs before any unsafe functions are called.
3. Unmanaged code debugging is enabled.
4. I know the symbols are loaded for the dll.
5. I know the version of the dll loaded by the debugger is the same used by the application.
6. I have cleaned and deleted the output directory then rebuilt.
7. They are using the same .NET version.

**Example:** if I were to add this to my watch window `MyDllType.SomeProperty` I would see this (in the watch window only):

`'MyDllType.SomeProperty' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' Message: "Cannot find the method on the object instance."`

*However*, if I were to add `Debug.Writeline(MyDllType.SomeProperty);` at that same exact point then I would get no exception and it would be correctly displayed in the output console.

**Furthermore:** if I were to create a list of a struct type defined in the dll project and add it to my watch window I would see this (in the watch window only):

```
// My Dll Project
public struct MyDllStruct
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
}

// Snippet from a function block in forms project
List<MyDllStruct> structList = new List<MyDllStruct>();

// Add a bunch of stuff to the list
// <-- Insert a breakpoint here
}
```

When i break and add `structList` to the watch window I get:

`Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x8004f0ed.`

*However*, once again I were to add `Debug.Writeline(structList.Count);` at that same exact point then I would get no exception and it the count would be correctly displayed in the output console.

**Full Example**:

```
// My Dll Project
public class MyDllType
{
    public MyDLLType()
    {
        this.someProperty = 123456;
    }

    private int someProperty;
    public int SomeProperty
    {
        get{ return this.someProperty; }
        set{ this.someProperty = value; }
    }
}
public struct MyDllStruct
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;
}

// My Forms Project
public class SomeController
{
    public SomeController()
    {
        this.dllType = new DllType();
        List<MyDllStruct> structList = new List<MyDllStruct>();

        // <-- For example, I get both aformentioned problems if i break here (or anywhere else these objects have been instantiated)
    }

    private MyDllType dllType;
}
```

As you could probably imagine, this is making it really hard to debug my application :) Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an answer as such, but some insight into the Watch-window vs Debug-printout mystery.

The Watch window in Visual Studio evaluates your input, say `structList`, using a built-in *managed expression evaluator*. As a runtime parser it is therefore a completely different beast than the compiler itself and only understands a subset of expressions. You can read a fine description of it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cw0h9312.aspx).

Therefore it's possible - and I seem to vaguely remember having experienced this myself - that this expression evaluator cannot properly handle types from an unsafe DLL. As a "lightweight compiler" it certainly does have some shortcomings, and this is possibly one of them.

On the other hand, `Debug.WriteLine()` works fine because the expression passed to it is processed at compile-time by the C# compiler itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your configuration manager and confirm that all projects compile to 'Any CPU'?  Long shot, but I know someone who had a similar problem, and I vaguely to remember he had projects that were set to a mix of x86 and Any CPU.

Comment: Yes, both are set to 'Any CPU'